# How do you implement a Class in Logramm?

Tags: class, oop, object, logramm

I've had a look into the Documentation and Examples (`http://83.212.101.132/`) but I can't find anything.

Is it even possible?

In large scale projects, like the one I'm working on right now, I most definitely prefer to use OOP. And not being able to support it would be a big letdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logramm was not designed as an object-oriented language. However, it's definitely doable, pretty much in the fashion Jerome described, but somewhat... smoother...

```
User :: {
    new(name,pass) => [
        .username: name,
        .password: pass
    ];

    print(this) => {
        out "Username: " + this.username;
        out "Password: " + this.password;
    }
}

user = User::new("newuser","newpass");
user.print();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I haven't found anything either, but I imagine this could be possible using functions, maybe? (the way Javascript does)

For example:

```
createNewUser(username,password) =>
{
    ==> [
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    ];
}

newUser = createNewUser("jerome","12345");
```

---

That's a dictionary/object actually. But it should do the trick, nope?

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much along the lines of what I was about to do. But there should be a more elegant approach.